# PHPExcel library get date

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, phpexcelreader, phpexcel-1.8.0

Using PHPExcel, I a trying to fetch data from Excel file and save it in MySql database using the following code:

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
$i=0;

$arr =array("","","","","","","");

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) 
{
 //  Read a row of data into an array
 $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
 foreach($rowData[0] as $k=>$v)
 {
    if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($v))
    {
        $arr[$i] = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate));
    }
    else
        $arr[$i] = $v;
    $i++;
}
```

This code gives following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime() must be an instance of PHPExcel_Cell, double given, called in ............

When I read columns as follows:

```
foreach($rowData[0] as $k=>$v)
{
    $arr[$i] = $v;
    $i++;
}
```

The date columns are read as normal text even if I set Cell Formatting to date in excel. In all, i have 3 date columns in each record of my excel file which may either have a date or will be blank.

The date column of excel has dates in format: d-m-Y. I want it to be fetch in the format: 'Y-m-d' if possible otherwise i will have to explode it and convert it manually. The date will be finally stored into mysql Date type column.

I read several articles at stackoverflow too, but couldn't get the perfect solution.

Comment: Can you var_dump($rowData); after getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$v` is just a numeric value, the serialized timestamp value used by MS Excel, no different to any other float value; it isn't possible to tell if `$v` represents a date or not without being able to access the format mask for the cell, which is why the `isDateTime()` method needs to read the cell itself to determine if it contains a date or not.

Ensure that your array is returned as an associative array (by setting the additional last argument for the method as `true`), which gives you the address of each cell:

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);
```

This will return an array indexed by its row address, as a nested array by column address, so your foreach will need to reflect the row number:

```
foreach($rowData[$row] as $k=>$v)
```

and $k will then be the column address.

You can then use $row and $k to get the cell, and pass that to the `isDateTime()` call:

```
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($sheet->getCell($k . $row)))
```

---

And note that

```
$arr[$i] = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate));
```

should be

```
$arr[$i] = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($v));
```

in your code